# sorting list based on other array contents

Tags: python, list, sorting

![enter image description here][1] consider the following code, i want to sort the odd list indices based on the even list indices in a GRADUEL order.

```
Processes = input("   Enter the  processes times & arrival times separated by a comma: ")
    BurstTimes = Processes[::2]
    ArrivalTimes = Processes[1::2]
```

Comment: What is "a GRADUEL order"?

Comment: Can you post a sample input and output

Comment: gradual order from the smallest to the largest

Comment: say 1st list (3,4,5) 2nd (3,6,8) i want to sort the first and each element in the first corresponding to the one with the same index in the 2nd list so i want to sort the first based on the "gradual sorting" of the 2nd list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
list1, list2 = [5, 4, 7, 1, 9], [3, 1, 10, 11, 5]
indices1 = range(len(list1))
indices1.sort(key=lambda x: list2[x])
list1 = map(lambda i: list1[i], indices1)
print list1, list2
```

*Gives:*

```
[4, 5, 9, 7, 1] [3, 1, 10, 11, 5]
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like what you want

```
processes = [12, 24, 36, 27, 45, 29, 35, 78, 23, 13]
burst_times = processes[::2]
arrival_times = processes[1::2]
zipped_set = zip(arrival_times,burst_times)
result_set = zip(*sorted(zipped_set))
result_set[1]
...(23, 12, 36, 45, 35)
```

Link to the fiddle http://repl.it/R6N
Feel free to use your own example in the fiddle